# how to force interfaceOrientation programmatically on iPhone?

Tags: iphone

how to force it show on UIDeviceOrientationPortrait only?

example 
layer1 display on UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft

when i pushViewController to layer2 it will auto show on UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
how can i force it to display UIDeviceOrientationPortrait?

Comment: Mybe this will help : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10146270/894671

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply implement `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` in your view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following in your layer2 viewController:

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had trouble with this.  Setting shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: makes it so that pushing viewControllers onto a stack will result in their views being oriented properly, but you can't *force* an orientation to portrait or landscape with an explicit function call.

The best I've seen so far is to handle the animation yourself (with a CATransform and related CoreAnimation calls).  It's not pretty.

If someone knows of a way to force the view to rotate (i.e. without pushing/popping view controllers, and without rotating the actual device) then please let me/us know.